# override adminhtml template

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, template

I would like to overide the following admin template `src/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/history.phtml`

This is what I made

## module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Cpy_Sales" setup_version="0.1.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

## Cpy/Sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

Already have one extend there for the items, this one seems to be fine

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_items">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Cpy_Sales::order/view/items.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name='order_history'>
            <arguments>
                <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Cpy_Sales::order/view/history.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then my custom template is in : `src/app/code/Cpy/Sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/history.phtml`
This template is basically the same but add an automatic "checked" attribute to the input `history[is_customer_notified]` so there is nothing very magical in there.

Comment: make sure your module is installed and enabled as well.

Comment: it is, already existing; and as I said the order_items is already overrided in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing

```
<referenceBlock name='order_history'>
    <arguments>
       <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Cpy_Sales::order/view/history.phtml</argument>
   </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

with

```
<referenceBlock name='order_history'>
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Cpy_Sales::order/view/history.phtml</argument>
     </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: I just figure it out, this is the way. I should have took more care about what I had above more than finding it on the web. I still don't know where this difference comes from. May be different magento version. Still it works, thanks !